# Learn "rust raspberrypi os tutorials" got error "rust-objcopy:no file or folder",make error 127

Tags: kernel, rust

I am learning https://github.com/rust-embedded/rust-raspberrypi-OS-tutorials by an new ubuntu 22.04 in virtualbox

1 install some tools:gcc,make,curl...

2 follow the readme said,install docker and "Ensure your user account is in the docker group":

```
sudo snap install docker
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
newgrp docker
```

then

```
docker run hello-world
```

success

2 install rust:

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

but got:

```
info:downloading installer
curl:(23) Failure writing output to destination
rustup: command failed:downloader https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-unknown-linux-gun/rustup-init /tmp/tmp.7fHoEietxL/rustup-init x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

I don't know why,so I install cargo:

```
sudo snap install rustup
```

3 then,in the code floder "rust-raspberrypi-OS-tutorials-master":

```
cargo install cargo-binutils rustfilt
```

finaly got:

```
Successfully installed cargo-binutils,rustfilt!
```

4 in floder 01_wait_forever,run

make qemu

got error:

```
Compiling kernel ELF - rpi3
Compiling mingo v0.1.0 (/home/wk/rust-raspberrypi-OS-tutorials-master/01_wait_forever)
Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 7.81s

Generating stripped binary
make: rust-objcopy:no file or floder
make:*** [Makefile:130:kernel8.img] error 127
```

I tried many times,but still can't make.Can you teach me?Thanks!

Comment: anything with `x86_64` is for a PC, not for a Raspberry Pi

Comment: but how to fix it?every step I have done is by the doc said